# Reduce padding in cell with lists in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

So I have a table that includes lists written with tabularx, however the lists have rather excess padding at the top and on the left. Is there a way to reduce this only for the space of this table?

Code:

```
% PRO CON TABLE FOR DIFFERENT TOOLKITS
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages} \\
\hline
QuTiP &
\begin{itemize}
\item Supervisor is one of the lead developers on the project, so can ask questions and get advice as needed.
\item Widely used, with 371 citations at time of writing, meaning tool may have more value
\end{itemize} & 
\begin{itemize}
\item Con
\item Con
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline
(... other lines ...)
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}
```

[image: Example of table with excess cell padding]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the `enumitem` package I have created a new `itemize`-like environment for the use in table cells:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}

\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,
                  topsep= 0pt,
                  partopsep=0pt,
                  leftmargin= *,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }

\begin{document}

% PRO CON TABLE FOR DIFFERENT TOOLKITS
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages} \\
\hline
QuTiP &
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Supervisor is one of the lead developers on the project, so can ask questions and get advice as needed.
\item Widely used, with 371 citations at time of writing, meaning tool may have more value
\end{tabitemize} & 
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Con
\item Con
\end{tabitemize}
\\
\hline
(... other lines ...)
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is absolutely fantastic, thank you! Upvoted but won't display as I'm new, but accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `enumitem` and a macro found on this site:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}%, after=\vspace*{-5\topsep}

% PRO CON TABLE FOR DIFFERENT TOOLKITS
\begin{table}[h]
\centering\sffamily\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, topsep=0pt, leftmargin=*, after ={\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip + \partopsep}}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{2}{>{\compress}X|}}
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages} \\ \hline
QuTiP &
\begin{itemize}
\item Supervisor is one of the lead developers on the project, so can ask questions and get advice as needed.
\item Widely used, with 371 citations at time of writing, meaning tool may have more value
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}
\item Con
\item Con
\end{itemize}
\\\hline
(... other lines ...)
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]